# Different screenshots from Headless vs Non Headless configuration in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to get the screenshot/pdf of this [URL](https://flexbooks.ck12.org/cbook/ck-12-interactive-algebra-2-for-ccss/section/1.4/primary/lesson/characteristics-of-polynomial-graphs-alg-2-ccss) => 
If I give the option {headless: false} - proper screenshot is generated but in headless mode, a couple of images are not rendering in the screenshot (one can see the try it button in the screenshot but not the image in headless mode).
Headless => [HEADLESS_PNG](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DmL6pkn_yh4q4rU7fQLVi-yxhYCdK00H/view?usp=sharing) 
Non-Headless => [NON_HEADLESS_PNG](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q-ENNohLavjQ3CZbxuLkpUZZYit7Iqdn/view?usp=sharing)

The code is

```
`(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setUserAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36');
    await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({
        'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8'
    })
    await page.goto(URL, {waitUntil: 'networkidle2', timeout: 0});
    await autoScroll(page);
    await delay(10000);
    await page.screenshot({path: 'non_headless.png', fullPage: true});
    await browser.close();
})();
async function delay(ms) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            resolve(1);
        }, ms)
    });
}
async function autoScroll(page){
    await page.evaluate(async () => {
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var totalHeight = 0;
            var distance = 100;
            var timer = setInterval(() => {
                var scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
                window.scrollBy(0, distance);
                totalHeight += distance;
                if(totalHeight >= scrollHeight){
                    clearInterval(timer);
                    resolve();
                }
            }, 100);
        });
    });
}`
```

Any help would be appreciated to get the same screenshot in headless mode as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try either increasing the waiting time by a few seconds (if the images aren't loading in before the screenshot) or setting the viewport:

```
await page.setViewport({ width: yourWidth, height: yourHeight });
```